# VariableThroughputTimer: No free threads left in worker pool jmeter

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, jmeter, throughput

I am using the Throughput Shaping Timer in JMeter
I am occasionally seeing warning messages such as the below:

2020-01-21 17:02:01,007 WARN k.a.j.t.VariableThroughputTimer: No free threads left in worker pool, made  316/500.0 samples
2020-01-21 17:02:02,009 WARN k.a.j.t.VariableThroughputTimer: No free threads left in worker pool, made  164/500.0 samples
2020-01-21 17:02:03,016 WARN k.a.j.t.VariableThroughputTimer: No free threads left in worker pool, made  263/500.0 samples
2020-01-21 17:02:04,009 WARN k.a.j.t.VariableThroughputTimer: No free threads left in worker pool, made  311/500.0 samples
2020-01-21 17:02:05,009 WARN k.a.j.t.VariableThroughputTimer: No free threads left in worker pool, made  288/500.0 samples

I am using Target Concurrency: ${__tstFeedback(rate_profile,100,5000,500)}

I need to get to 500 tps, I am not able to get more than 270 tps out of a jmeter server instance with this plugin.

Monitors indicate CPU, Disk, Network, Memory resources are available, however, test start logging this warning

Could you please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With this config ${__tstFeedback(rate_profile,100,5000,500)}, the number of threads used by the jmeter process is 120 in the VM,
I used another config $ {__ tstFeedback (rate_profile, 300,3000,0.75)} so that the number of threads increases to 320,
therefore the number of TPS has increased to 500 TPS.
```

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you set too low `Spare threads ratio`, try increasing:

- Starting concurrency
- Spare threads ration

for a factor of 2x.

[image]

Also consider correlating the number of threads with the application response time.

It also worth checking JMeter's JVM metrics like [heap space](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/java-heap-space-memory-size-jvm.html) usage and [garbage collection](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/garbage-collection-java/) intervals, JMeter's JVM heap usage needs to be between 40 and 70% for optimal performance

[image]

JMeter JVM settings can be monitored using i.e. [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/)

If a single JMeter instance cannot produce the required load you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)

---

Also remember that it might be the case your application isn't capable of responding fast enough so it worth checking its health metrics, performance metrics and logs as well.